# django - many-to-many and one-to-many relationships

Tags: django, database, many-to-many, many-to-one

I am working in django, am planning a database for rides for users.

- each **User** can be on multiple **Rides** (over time) and each **Ride** can have multiple **Users** (passengers) in it.
- Also, for each Ride there has to be only one Driver (also a **User**) so I think I have a **many-to many** relationship between the Rides and Users tables for what **user** is on what **ride**, and also a **One-To-Many** relationship between the Rides's Driver_id and the User_id. right?

**My questions are-**

1. I saw in the django docs that I should put a many-to-many field in **One** of the models. Does it matter which one? and also, does it create a new table like rides_users?
2. and also, what is the difference (**in One-To-many relationship**) between using a **foreignKey** field and a **OneToManyField** field?

**EDIT:**

Currently, there are my models:

```
def get_image_path(models.Model):
    return os.path.join('photos',str(instance.id),filename)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, black=True, null=True)

class Ride(models.Model):
    driver=models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="r_driver")
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination, related_name="r_final_destination")
    leaving_time=models.DateTimeField()
    num_of_spots=models.IntergerField()
    passengers=models.ManyToMany(UserProfile, related_name="r_passengers")
    mid_destinations=models.ManyToMany(Destination, related_name="r_mid_destinations")

class Destination(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

As you can see, each Ride has **multiple** mid_destination and **multiple** passengers. a Ride also has **One** driver and **One** final destination.

**The Issue is -** when a **User**  adds a **Ride**, I want the *driver*, *destination* and *mid_destinations* and the rest of the fields to be set by the **User** (the driver is user adding the Ride), **Except** for the *passengers* field. I want the other Users to add themselves to the ride, so when the Ride is created the User (driver) doesn't have to set the passengers.

How do I go about it? and also, any other suggestions about the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a OneToManyField.

It doesn't matter from a practical point of view which side the ManyToManyField lives on. Personally, I'd put it on Ride, both to avoid changing the User model and because conceptually I'd say that rides are the main objects here.

And yes, adding the field will automatically create the linking table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant a ManyToOne field,  is there such a thing?  And if so,  do I use foreignKey or ManyToOne? For the many to one relationship

Comment: No, there is not such a thing either. Why would you think there is? The documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: I remembered something related to it.. never mind, guess I was wrong. thanks anyway!

Comment: I edited the question and added another issue I have with my current code. would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Don't do that, please: ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is probably something like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    driver = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='r_driver')
    # you need to use a related name if you want to link to the same model more than once
    passengers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="r_passengers")
```

Comment: Thabks for your answer.  What is the meaning of the "to=user" in the foreign key?

Comment: coming from `def __init__(self, to, to_field=None, rel_class=ManyToOneRel,
                 db_constraint=True, **kwargs):`

Comment: okay, why did you put it on the ForeignKey field and not in the ManyToMany field? I mean, I am not really sure what is it doing and so far I haven't used it, just put the model name like in the ManyToMany. Also - I edited my question with my new Ride and other models and also added a another issue I have in the question. any help would be appreciated